# What is the purpose of using myevent(this,EventArgs.Empty)?

Tags: c#, events, delegates

I am currently learning about delegates and events in csharp.I have the following set of codes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

public delegate void mydel(object sender, EventArgs e); 

class event1
{
    public event mydel myevent;

    public void onfive()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I am onfive event");
        Console.ReadKey();
        if (myevent != null)
        { 
            myevent(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}

public class test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        event1 e1 = new event1();
        e1.myevent += new mydel(fun1);

        Random ran = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int rn = ran.Next(6); 
            Console.WriteLine(rn);
            Console.ReadKey();

            if (rn == 5)
            {
                e1.onfive(); 
            }
        }
    }

    public static void fun1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" i am surplus function called due to use of '+=' ");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Whenever i put the following lines in comment the fun1() function is not called.Why it it so?

```
if (myevent != null)
 { 
  myevent(this,EventArgs.Empty);
 }
```

what is the purpose of these lines?

Comment: Tutorial on C# events: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That bit of code is what raises the event.  If the event is not raised then the event handler is not executed.

A delegate is an object that refers to a method and an event is sort of like a collection of delegates.  If you don't add any handlers to an event then there is no collection, hence the check for `null`.  If the event is not `null` then that means that handlers have been registered.  The line inside the `if` statement raises the event, which means invoking each of the delegates in the collection.  As each delegate is invoked, so the method it refers to is executed.  The method that gets executed is your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

**EventArgs :**
The EventArgs are arguments that the implementor of this event may find useful. With OnClick it contains nothing good, but in some events, like say in a GridView 'SelectedIndexChanged', it will contain the new index, or some other useful data.

**EventArgs.Empty:** Used to Pass the value to event handlers that are associated with events that do not have data.

Your event is of type **mydel**.

public mydel myevent; **// declaring an event of type mydel with signature void mydel()**

Hope this might give you some spark.

Answer (score 0):

```
   if (myevent != null) //Checks so you instantiated a event
   { 
        myevent(this,EventArgs.Empty); // {this} will be equal to the sender in delegete myDel, {EventArgs.Empty} is since you are not passing any arguments to your delegate. 
   }
```